# Can you use browserify without bundling?

Tags: client-side, browserify, javascript

I have quite a few co-workers and friends with existing brownfield, messy javascript applications who would like to start transitioning to some sort of js module system. I've tried to help them out in the past by showing them how to refactor to requirejs but I'm starting to think that is a bad approach.

The problem is usually that the nature of their globals-all-over-the-place code conflicts with the asynchronous nature of AMD, and as much as I believe in the AMD approach, they have bigger concerns than my lectures on the "proper" way to do module loading.

Browserify in the meantime removes the async consideration and is more straightforward but adds in a whole build step. For people who are not using bundling or any sort of a build process (or just the default one in visual studio) this is again, too much overhead.

So what I really want is a simple module system that allows people to `define` and `require` things. This is a half-step toward getting things working properly, they can include their dependencies with regular script tags and define them into the module system manually. [I even wrote such a system](https://github.com/togakangaroo/simple-modules) because...hey, that's really easy.

Today someone pointed out to me that it should be possible to actually use just the client-side pieces of Browserify to achieve this. I agree. However, I can't really find any documentation anywhere nor just the Browserify client-side stuff in isolation.

Comment: I suspect that's not possible... You'd have to run the entire browserify process on the client side for every page load, and that's usually on the seconds scale. Browserify is pretty magical, but I do believe you'll need the server-side bundling to make it work...

Comment: @urban_racoons but isn't the bundle that browserify generates just essentially each js file surrounded by a `define(...)` and concatenated together? Why couldn't you just call define manually from your application? Or does it do something more? I'm not really sure since - as I implied - I'm squarely in the AMD camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sitting down and dissecting a built browserify file I've concluded that no, what I want to do is not possible.

For one thing browserify doesn't seem to expose a define or even a require keyword. For another, it does some minor rewriting of the combined modules which would be very difficult to achieve during runtime.

Comment: found something called Dynamic Require and its awesome... https://github.com/manvalls/drq

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a dynamic module loader that works well with Browserify. You can use it for development to expose "require" globally on the client side. Works great.

https://github.com/manvalls/drq

Comment: Sure but this doesn't really work for the stated problem where brownfield code using the dependency isn't written as an asynchronous callback. This looks cool, but if you're starting with a greenfield app why not do something like jspm?

Comment: I"m sure you're right. It's so hard to get some points on this place!

Answer (score -2):

A solution to your problem could be:

https://github.com/LarsBV/browser-node-loader

I wrote this due to various sourcemap bugs in browsers, and too many / alternative, 
configuration ways in gulp/browserify/watchify.

It has a build step but it only needs to be run when there is new dependencies.

I don't recommend this approach for production, but it is so much easier in development.

This is very new, and untested in anything but latest chrome, firefox, with some adjustments 
in the generated script I think it will work in even ie6.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting but pretty much the exact opposite of what I want to use browserfy for. I'm not looking for module loading. Rewriting an existing messy project to do module loading is really tough. I just want the module system part of it. As you say - your project is not for production. My intent is specifically to help transition existing code to a better architecture.